# How do I modify buttons in .textinput?

Tags: python, button

I'm trying to do a menu or something like that

Here's the code:

```
from turtle import TurtleScreen, RawTurtle, TK

root = TK.Tk()
root.title("ArMoon")
canvas = TK.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=700)
canvas.pack()
win = TurtleScreen(canvas)
dali = RawTurtle(win)

def Entrada():
    return win.textinput("Figura"," 1. Operando\n 2. Sumar operandos\
    \n 3. Reiniciar\n 4. Salir\n ")



while True:
    x = Entrada()
    if x == "4" or x == "":
        break
    oper = x.split()
    print(oper)
    x = oper[0]
    print(x)
    #if x <= 0:



win.mainloop()
```

The problem is that when I run the program, in the small window of the text input, they show me two buttons, I don't mind, I like them but is there a way to modify what do they do?

The "Ok" button seems to work fine but when I press the "cancel" button I get an error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File "C:\Users\Lobo\Desktop\TORTUGA\Borrador v2.py", line 21, in
> <module>
> 
>     oper = x.split()
> 
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I would like to modify it so when I press it just run 'break' to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should modify your code such that:

```
x = Entrada()
if x is None or x == "4":
   break
```

Because when cancel button return None (something like null-pointer in C) rather than an empty string

Comment: Please don't forget accept answer =) (a tick under the vote bar). You also earned +2 to rep.

Answer (score 1):

you can store the value of textinput into a variable

example:

```
val = turtle.textinput(title, prompt)
if not val:
   print("blank selected")
elif val == "None"
   print("Cancel Pressed")
else:
   print("do something")
```